# DateTimePicker for custom calendars

Tags: .net, winforms, calendar, globalization

Do you know any DateTimePickers for calendars other than the Gregorian calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific as to which type of Calendar you are interested in?

There is a Farsi calendar control available on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/FarsiLibrary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try the RadControls:
RadCalendar for ASP.NET AJAX: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/calendar.aspx
RadCalendar for WinForms: http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/calendar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you cant change the culture of a datetimepicker is not allow  natively
check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19)