# Changing Calendar Type in DateTimePicker , C#?

Tags: datetimepicker, persian

Is it possible to change type of calendar in DateTimePicker (C#) ?
e.g : I'm gonna replace Persian Calendar with the default calendar in DateTimePicker !
Thanks

Comment: I've written a Persian Date Time Picker with Javascript : http://mds-soft.persianblog.ir/post/121/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx):

> The DateTimePicker control only
>   supports Gregorian calendars.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607658/datetimepicker-for-custom-calendars) discusses your options if you're open to non-Microsoft controls.